# How to change all text of web page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I want to change all of the text in the web page with JavaScript

I want to make an application that's can change the text of an HTML page for replace correct text instead of wrong or incorrect text.

you think i want to make an app just like Google translator;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on your question, but if you just want to replace the entire text of a page, just do

```
document.body.innerHTML = 'replacement HTML';
```

That won't affect the title, but you can change the title via

```
document.title = 'replacement plain text';
```

If you want to replace a web-page with text, then you can do

```
while (document.body.firstChild)
  document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myText));
```

Comment: innerHTML include some html tags and if I replace with new text the HTML layout are break and the new page dont show like the original page

Comment: @user986739, Do you want to change "*all* the text" in the page or just a portion?

Comment: I want to change "all of text"
I say you think like google translator, how it works?
all of page is original and just "all of texts" are translated to new text

Comment: @sma6871, If you want to change the whole page text, use `document.body.innerHTML` as I explained.

Comment: in the innerHTML we see tags and other HTML things, but I just need the text.
Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all divs and layouts and want only to to change the text, you cannot change the `innerhtml` of the body. You must separately change the `innerhtml` of all the elements in the page. It's straightforward but tedious.